# how to prove $B-A\in \mathcal M(\mu)$ such that $A,B\in \mathcal M(\mu)$ and $A$ is subset of $A$?

Tags: real-analysis

Definition: A subset $A \subset \Omega$ is said to be $\mu ^{\star}$-measurable if 
$$\mu^{\star}(E)= \mu^{\star}(E\bigcap A)+\mu^{\star}(E\bigcap A^{\prime})$$ for all $E\subset \Omega$.
The set of all  $\mu ^{\star}$ measurable sets is denoted by $\mathcal M(\mu)$.

If we have $A,B\in \mathcal M(\mu)$  and $A\subset B$  does $B-A\in \mathcal M(\mu)$ follow?

Thaks in advance

for example if $A\in \mathcal M(\mu)$ means $\mu^{\star}(E)= \mu^{\star}(E\bigcap A)+\mu^{\star}(E\bigcap A^{\prime})$

we must prove $\mu^{\star}(E)= \mu^{\star}(E\bigcap(B- A))+\mu^{\star}(E\bigcap (B-A)^{\prime})$

Comment: What does $\mu ^{\star}$ measurable mean?  Is that an outer measure or something?

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan:$\mu ^{\star}$ mean outter measure.

Comment: Aren't outer measures always defined for any set?  So what does it mean to say $\mu ^{\star}$ measurable?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan A set $E\in \mathcal{P}(X)$ is $\mu^{\ast}$-measurable if for any $F\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ we have that $\mu^{\ast}(F)=\mu^{\ast}(F\cup E) + \mu^{\ast}(F\setminus E)$.

Comment: @enjoysmath I read your pdf
But it was all practice
Not Solution

Comment: @enjoysmath If it is possible
Please tell me
Which Exercises is the answer of this problem.Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan if it possible help me to solve this problem.Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @pualambagher If you want anyone to help you, first try getting your question reopened, by editing the question and providing more details, like the ones provided in the comments section about what mu star measurable means, and preferably what attempts you've made to solve the problem already.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I edited my question ,and Thank you For tips
.

Comment: It is the caratheodory construction of getting a measure from a outer measure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [nice exercise-based proof.](http://www.probability.net/WEBcaratheodory.pdf#page=10&zoom=auto,53,442)